# Infinispan + WildFly + Spring

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

In my Spring 1.4 app I have configured a following cache manager:

```
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() throws Exception {
    JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();
    EmbeddedCacheManager embededCacheManager = (EmbeddedCacheManager) jndiTemplate.lookup("java:jboss/infinispan/container/CONTAINER");
    SpringEmbeddedCacheManager cacheManager = new SpringEmbeddedCacheManager(embededCacheManager);
}
```

I'm running WildFly 10.

In `pom.xml` I have defined this dependency for Infinispan:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
    <artifactId>infinispan-spring</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

When I deploy the application Infinispan JNDI lookup finds cache container defined in the WildFly configuration and everything starts fine. However, when I run the method which uses cache I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.DefaultCache does not implement the requested interface org.infinispan.commons.api.BasicCache
```

Whats the cause of this error and how to fix it?

Comment: It looks like you're using an incompatible version of Infinispan. If you're deploying the app in wildfly, maybe you should flag that as provided if wildfly gives that to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is what solved the issue. I had to add dependencie `org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan` to the MANIFEST.
So, my POM has `maven-war-plugin` defined like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Dependencies>org.infinispan, org.infinispan.commons, org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan export</Dependencies>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```